# What's the minimum sample required for correlation analysis (linear model in R)

Tags: r, statistics

I'm trying to perform correlation analysis with 
R's linear model

> lm()

I'm wondering what is the reasonable minimum sample for it?
Is there any rule for determining that?

Comment: This question belongs here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I think if you have two data columns or vectors with minimum two data points then the lm function should work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As a rule of thumb, <del>20, 30, 1000, samples</del> [As a rule of thumb, you should be wary of rules of thumb](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/56477/7744). Excluding perhaps that "less is more, except of course for sample size" (Cohen & Cohen, 1983: 169-171).

You could ask your question on https://stats.stackexchange.com/ but they're probably going to give you answers that might not be the round number that you're looking for. For example:

- [Is the number 20 magic?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/56465/is-the-number-20-magic)
- [Is there a reference that suggest using 30 as a large enough sample size?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2541/is-there-a-reference-that-suggest-using-30-as-a-large-enough-sample-size)
- [Rules of thumb for minimum sample size for multiple regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10079/rules-of-thumb-for-minimum-sample-size-for-multiple-regression)
- [What is a reasonable sample size for correlation analysis for both overall and sub-group analyses?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/15842/what-is-a-reasonable-sample-size-for-correlation-analysis-for-both-overall-and-s)
- [30 Samples. Standard, Suggestion, or Superstition?](http://statswithcats.wordpress.com/2010/07/11/30-samples-standard-suggestion-or-superstition/)
- etc.

You'll get more useful responses if you edit your question here to include a [**reproducible example**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1036500) that resembles your actual use-case and then ask for help coding calculations of relevant measures of error. You might explore the `pwr` package before you edit your question (see here for examples: http://www.statmethods.net/stats/power.html).

Do a bit of googling to find the names of error measures you think will be useful to you. You might start with these:

Lenth, R. V. (2001), Some Practical Guidelines for Effective Sample Size Determination, The American Statistician, 55, 187-193.

Wheeler, R. E. (1974), 'Portable Power', Technometrics, 16, 193–201.

Cohen, J. & Cohen, P. (1983). Applied multiple regression/correlation analysis for the behavioral sciences (2nd ed.).(Hillsdale, NJ: Erlbaum)